# Vector of double to save distance of every sides in a polygon

Tags: c++, vector

everyone I want to do a function in a class Polygon who will be save the size of every sides of the polygon in a vector of double. My polygon is build thanks to the class Point. So I success to know how many point I have in my polygon and to print the drawing of the polygon to the screen. But the function to get the sides of every sides of the polygon thanks to the point,  I still have not succeeded

This is my class Point :

```
 Point::Point(double x, double y)
 {
  _x = x;
  _y = y;
 }
 Point::Point(const Point& other) 
 {
  _x = other._x;
  _y = other._y;
 }
 double Point::getX() const
 {
  return _x;
 }
double Point::getY() const
{
  return _y;
}
double Point::distance(const Point& other)
{
 return sqrt((getX() - other._x) * (getX() - other._x) + (getY() - other._y) *(getY() - other._y));
}
```

This is my header of class Polygon :

```
 class Polygon
 {
  public:
   Polygon();
   ~Polygon();
   int numOfPoints() const;
   vector<Point> getPoints() const;
   vector<double> getSides() const;
  protected:
   std::vector<Point> _points;
  };
```

and the cpp of Polygon :

```
 Polygon::Polygon(){}
 Polygon::~Polygon(){}
 int Polygon::numOfPoints() const
 {
  return _points.size();
 }
 vector<Point> Polygon::getPoints() const
 {
  return _points;
 }
 vector<double> Polygon::getSides() const
 {
  vector<double> sides;
 }
```

So I dont know how can I get the size of every sides thanks to class Point. I think it can be do thanks to the function distance of point, but I don't know how. If you can help me.
Thanks You !

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Well, you would need to be sure which points are standing for which corner in your std::vector<Point> _points. Why don't you try to give every point his own variable, or try to use a map with an enum which defines the position of the point? It is completely possible without this, but you would have 4 points in your vector which are not really identifiable. When you know which points you need to calculate which side you can, indeed, just use your distance function.

Comment: Sossenbinder, I have to complete the header so edti of the header is forbidden in my exercise, because this i have a problem and I don't understand how to do this

Comment: Yeah, you need the two points which are the start and end point of your side. However, I think your problem is that you are not really able to identify which points are stored at which vector cell right now. Edit: Oh, okay, my bad. Didnt see your comment in time,

Comment: Can you help me to resolve the problem without editing the header file ?

Comment: I don't quite see the problem. You just need two points, which you are sure are defining one side. You then take the first Point out of the vector, and call your Distance()-Function on it while passing the other point as parameter. I hope that's what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

First the small point: The following avoids double calculation of the differences (though compiler might optimise, it's better not to rely on it for doing so...).

```cpp
double Point::distance(const Point& other)
{
    double dx = _x - other._x;
    double dy = _y - other._y;
    return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
```

Then you have to iterate over all the points; you need at least two to have any distances at all, but two is the degenerate case (one distance only, all other numbers n result in n distances...):

```cpp
vector<double> Polygon::getSides() const
{
    vector<double> sides;
    if(points.size() > 2)
    {
        sides.reserve(points.size());
        std::vector<Point>::iterator end = points.end() - 1;
        for(std::vector<Point>::iterator i = points.begin(); i != end; ++i)
            sides.push_back(i->distance(*(i + 1)));
    }
    if(points.size() >= 2)
        sides.push_back(points.front().distance(points.back()));
    return sides;
}
```

Explanation:

```cpp
if(points.size() > 2)
```

Only if we have more than two points, so triangle at least, we have true polyone. We now calculate the distances of this one, e. g. for a square ABCD the distances AB, BC, CD. Note that the distance DA is yet missing...

```cpp
    sides.reserve(points.size());
```

A polygon with n points has n sides. This prevents reallocation.

```cpp
    std::vector<Point>::iterator end = points.end() - 1;
```

end() points one past the end. Want to calculate distances i, i+1, so last element must be skipped.

```cpp
    for(std::vector<Point>::iterator i = points.begin(); i != end; ++i)
        sides.push_back(i->distance(*(i + 1)));
```

Now calculating the distances...

```cpp
if(points.size() >= 2)
    sides.push_back(points.front().distance(points.back()));
```

This catches two cases: For true polygones this adds the last side closing it (in the example above: DA). Additionally, it handles the degenerate case of a single line (i = 2).

Actually, this could have been placed as well in front of the for loop. My variant calculates for points ABCD AB BC CD DA, the alternative DA, AB, BC, CD.

You might have noticed that we reserve only in the case of a true polygone. In the degenerate case, we are only inserting a single element, so it does not matter if we allocate the inner array before via reserve or at inserting the element...

Oh, and if you want to save a line of code:

```cpp
for(std::vector<Point>::iterator i = points.begin() + 1; i != points.end(); ++i)
    sides.push_back(i->distance(*(i - 1)));
```

Effectively the same, just reverted the points (calculating BA instead of AB).

Comment: Where I insert the second portion of code in my function getSides(), and can you explain your code a little more ?

Comment: @rony.stackoverflow Added a detailed explanation... Note that there was a bug in, due to a typo. Must be end() - 1 instead of end - 2...

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the points in the polygon, calculating the distance to the previous point.

Something like the following should work (untested):

```
vector<double> Polygon::getSides() const {
    vector<double> sides;
    for(auto it = this->_points.begin(); it != this->_points.end(); it++) {
        if(it == this->_points.begin())
            sides.push_back(it->distance(*(this->_points.end() - 1)));
        else
            sides.push_back(it->distance(*(it - 1)));
    }
    return sides;
}
```

This starts at the first point and calculates the distance to the last point. For each point after that it calculates the distance to the previous point. Each time adding the distance to the output vector.

Note that I have assumed that the polygon is closed, i.e. the first point is connected to the last point. If the polygon contains no points, the return vector will be empty. If it contains only one point, it will contain a single element [0].  This results from calculating the distance from a point to the same point.

See this tutorial for more info on iterating over vectors: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/iterators.html